# Azure Blob - Upload a very large file in parallel

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload very large file into Azure Blob store. I am using Java with Azure SDK. I want to do this in following manner -

1. Split the large file in smaller chunks.
2. Upload all the chunks in parallel to Azure Blob Store.

I can do these tasks by writing the code to split and upload using multiple threads but I am looking for something provided by the SDK itself to do the above tasks. The examples or samples that I found where doing these steps explicitly. As of now, I am uploading using following code -

```
blob.upload(stream, stream.length());
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

UPDATE -

After inputs from @Gaurav Mantri, my updated code looks like

```
BlobRequestOptions blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
blobRequestOptions.setConcurrentRequestCount(8);
blobRequestOptions.setSingleBlobPutThresholdInBytes(65000000);
blob.upload(stream, stream.length(), null, blobRequestOptions ,null);
```

I am uploading file of size 3GB. Still I am not sure whether the file is getting split or not because there is no improvement in time taken for upload.

Comment: the SDK copy is synchronous. better performance would be achieved thru AzCopy, if you are copying between two azure storage accounts. Call the utility from Java to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @harishr I am uploading a very large file from my local windows machine to Azure Blob Store. Can I use AzCopy in this case as well?

Comment: AzCopy can certainly be used for this purpose. This utility is meant for that purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [`BlobRequestOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._blob_request_options) class in Java SDK. There are two methods there that are of your interest:

- [`setConcurrentRequestCount(final Integer concurrentRequestCount)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._blob_request_options.setconcurrentrequestcount#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob__blob_request_options_setConcurrentRequestCount_final_Integer_)

> Sets the concurrent number of simultaneous requests per operation. The
>   default concurrent request count is set in the client and is by
>   default 1, indicating no concurrency.

- [`setSingleBlobPutThresholdInBytes(final Integer singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._blob_request_options.setsingleblobputthresholdinbytes#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob__blob_request_options_setSingleBlobPutThresholdInBytes_final_Integer_)

> Sets the threshold size used for writing a single blob to use. The
>   default threshold size is set in the client and is by default 32MB.
>   You can change the threshold size on this request by setting this
>   property.

What this property will do is that if it finds that blob you're trying to upload is of size larger than the value specified, SDK will automatically break that blob into chunks and upload those chunks.

Comment: How to govern whether this is really happening or not? I have two statements

    blob.upload(stream, stream.length());
and
    blob.upload(stream, stream.length(), null, blobRequestOptions, null);

But the time taken in executing both the statements is same. As of now I am using 64MB as threshold value and 8 concurrent requests.

Comment: You can trace the requests through a tool like Fiddler.

Comment: I don't think this is doing what I want. Because I have tried with concurrency values 1,2,4 and 8 but every time the time taken in upload is same

Comment: Unfortunately I have not used Java SDK so I am going just by the documentation. Have you checked the network requests in Fiddler?

Comment: Yup, requests are same in case of concurrency and no concurrency.

Comment: Requests will be same but do you see them being sent sequentially? i.e. one request sent, the next request is sent only after response is received for the 1st request.

Comment: There is only one request. no multiple requests are created.

Comment: How big is the file? What is the value you're setting in singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes? Please edit your question and include your code where you're setting these request options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171224/discussion-between-abi-pat-and-gaurav-mantri).